# Android GoogleCloudMessaging - "INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am updating my GCM code and trying to implement [this code](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register), but it will not compile because of the `GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE` field:

> INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE cannot be resolved or is not a field

What could the problem be?

NB - `GoogleCloudMessaging` resolves fine.

Comment: prolly you are using older library ... problem is that there is no mark in documentation in which gsm version this field was added ...

Comment: As far as I can see in Android SDK Manager, everything is up-to-date. And, as instructed elsewhere, I imported this lib into my Eclipse project: `<android-sdk>\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs\google-play-services.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Check these three conditions:

- Appropriate version of [Google Play Services](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html).
- Get a Project ID generated by the [Google Developers Console](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/) if you intend to generate tokens.
- Please make sure that you are not calling the method **instanceID.getToken** in the main thread; instead, use a service that extends IntentService.
- The listener service's onTokenRefresh method should be invoked if the GCM registration token has been refreshed